# Struct as parameter in function with Completion - Swift

Tags: swift, parameter-passing, func

I'm in trouble, there is the possibility to set a parameter of function inside the Completion? In specific I have 2 structs and I want that the user will select one of them. My code is something like this:

```
struct Photo: Decodable {
...
}
//Function
func fetchPhotos(url: String, completion: @escaping ([Photo]?, Error?) -> ()) {
...
}
```

Basically I want that instead of the [Photo]? in the Completion, there will be parameter that I can set before. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the other struct and what do you need to do with the parameter, please explain more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my struct will be the same as the "Photo" but is named "Album". So basically I'm parsing 2 JSON files and they have different elements to parse reason for what I need to chose the first or the second struct for parse correctly the JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a protocol, and confirm to it on both them and pass that as argument, you don't care what type the object is it you just need to know how to use it thats why after completion you simply cast its type is you need to, check the code below, I added `Video` `struct` as your 2nd one since you don't have one in the question.

```
protocol Switchable: Decodable {

}

struct Video: Switchable {

}
struct Photo: Switchable {

}
//Function
func fetchPhotos(url: String, completion: @escaping ([Switchable]?, Error?) -> ()) {
     completion([],nil)
}
//Check on the result after completion is called
let v: [Switchable] = [Video(), Video()]

if let photos = v as? [Photo] {
    print("its photos", photos)
}
if let videos = v as? [Video] {
    print("its videos ",videos)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! let v: [switchable] = [Video(), Video()]  shouldn't be let v: [switchable] = [Video(), Photo()]. 

Then, what should I put inside the protocol?

Comment: i don't fully understand what you trying to do, but it works if you done it like that too

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Mohmmad S answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54979756/5501940), for implementing `fetchPhotos`, it seems that using enums would be more appropriate because in the `completion` parameter we are asking as "result OR error".

You could implement something like:

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    case notFound
}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(CustomError)
}

protocol Switchable: Decodable { }
struct Video: Switchable { }
struct Photo: Switchable { }
```

Hence, `fetchPhotos` as:

```
func fetchPhotos(url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Switchable]>) -> Void) {
    // in case of error:
    let error: CustomError? = CustomError.notFound
    if let error = error {
        completion(.failure(error))
    }

    // in case of success - videos:
    completion(.success([Video(), Video()]))

    // in case of success - photos:
    completion(.success([Photo(), Photo()]))
}
```

Calling it as:

```
fetchPhotos(url: "...") { result in
    switch result {

    case .success(let photos):
        // in case of photos
        if let photos = photos as? [Photo] { /**/ }

        // in case of videos
        if let videos = photos as? [Video] { /**/ }

        // in case of mix of photos and videos, you should iterate through it and check each object
        photos.forEach({ photo in
            if let media = photo as? Photo {

            } else if let media = photo as? Video {

            }
        })

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```